# SELECT , GROUP AND DISPLAY IN TABULAR FORM AND COUNTING INSTANCES

Tags: mysql, pivot

[image]

Answer to this query was received as -

```
SELECT location,
   AVG(CASE WHEN qtr = 'Q1' THEN achievement END) q1-average,
   AVG(CASE WHEN qtr = 'Q2' THEN achievement END) q2-average
FROM sourcetable 
GROUP BY location
```

Now, the problem is while counting the instances generated with the above query. The final output I require as shown below -

[image: Final Output format]

Can such output be generated using a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT location,
   AVG(CASE WHEN qtr = 'Q1' THEN achievement END) `q1-average`,
   AVG(CASE WHEN qtr = 'Q2' THEN achievement END) `q2-average`,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN achievement BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN 1 END) `3.0-4.0`,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN achievement BETWEEN 4 AND 5 THEN 1 END) `4.0-5.0`,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN achievement BETWEEN 5 AND 6 THEN 1 END) `5.0-6.0`,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN achievement BETWEEN 6 AND 7 THEN 1 END) `6.0-7.0`
FROM sourcetable 
GROUP BY location
```

In that form the border value (for example, 4.0) will be calculated both in lower and in upper range. To prevent this use double compare (for example `COUNT(CASE WHEN achievement >= 3 AND achievement < 4 THEN 1 END)`) instead of BETWEEN.

Comment: I tried with COUNT(CASE WHEN achievement >= 3 AND achievement < 4 THEN 1 END) and it perfectly works. Output is exactly what I was looking for. Thank your so much :-))